# Calling functions from main python

Tags: python, class

I have some python 3.4 code that works fine:

```
def run():
    m = 0
    while m != 1:    
        p = input('Please choose p: ')
        p = makeInt(p)
        #Some other code
        print(p)
        m = makeInt(input('Enter 1 if you would like to quit: '))

def makeInt(i):
    try:
        i = int(i)
    except ValueError:
        i = input('Incorrect input! Enter your answer: ')
        i = makeInt(i)
    return i

#Some other functions    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I want to put all this code in a class (Except possibly `if __name__ ==`...) When I put all the code including `if __name__ ==`... in a class like so:

```
class Foo(object):
    def run(self):
        m = 0
        while m != 1:    
            p1 = input('Please choose p: ')
            p1 = self.makeInt(p1)
            #Some other code
            print(p1)
            m = self.makeInt(input('Enter 1 if you would like to quit: '))

    def makeInt(self, i):
        try:
            i = int(i)
        except ValueError:
            i = input('Incorrect input! Enter your answer: ')
            i = self.makeInt(i)
        return i
    #Some other functions and stuff

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        run()
```

I get the following error: `TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.  When I remove the self argument from `run()` it runs until `makeInt()` is called and then I get: `NameError: name 'makeInt' is not defined`.  I get the same error if I take the if statement out of the class and call `Foo.run()`.  I have some other code earlier in this program that works when I call functions of a class from another function in that same class.  I realize I don't have to put all my code in a class, but in this case I want to. Why am I getting these errors and what can I do to put my working code in a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you wrap your code within a class, your `run()` is a method now. You should remove your `main` from your class by unindenting it and initialize an instance of your class:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Foo().run()
```

Answer (score 4):

As others mentioned, by putting your functions in a class, you've made them methods, that means they need an instance of this class as first argument. So you can indeed call your `run` method using `Foo().run()` as `Foo()` will create an instance of `Foo`.

Another way (e.g. if you don't need the class for anything else than encapsulation) is to make them [static](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29#Static_methods), using the [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator:

```
class Foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def run():
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def makeInt(i):
        ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Foo.run() # don't need an instance as run is static
```

In Python, a method can be static, i.e. no need for any special argument, a class method, i.e. first argument is the class itself, or a standard method, i.e. the first argument is an instance of the class.

Comment: But if you are using a class only as a namespace, why not just use a module?

Comment: Well, I agree with you, but that's a question better asked to the OP who specifically wanted to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It thinks the guard is a part of your class due to the indentation: you have your guard indented to the same level as the other class members. Unindent the

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

Also change it to be

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

and then instantiate a new object of type Foo in your newly created main() function

```
def main():
  newFoo = Foo()
  newFoo.run()
```